# Error parameters Twig with Path() Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, path, twig

I got error

> No route found for "POST
>   /module/getinfo/0/0/1454306400000/1455256800000"

The code on index.html.twig:

```
var desde_=1454306400000;
var hasta_=1455256800000;
var url = "{{ path('module_getinfo') }}"+desde_+"/"+hasta_
```

to get something like this:

`url = /module/getinfo/1454306400000/1455256800000`

the routing.yml is:

```
module_getinfo:
    pattern: /getinfo/{desde}/{hasta}/
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Module/Module:getInfo,desde:0,hasta:0}
```

I want to create a custom variable on javascript, what can I do ?

Thank you !

PD. Sorry for my english, I'm still learning jejeje

Answer (score 5):

If you don't pass the values of the route placeholders to the `path()` function, it'll use the default values (both set to 0).

If you can't pass the values, because they are only available in JavaScript, consider using string replacing techniques:

```
var url = "{{ path('module_getinfo', { desde: '%desde%', hasta: '%hasta%' }) }}"
    .replace('%desde%', desde_)
    .replace('%hasta%', hasta_)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use what @wouter J  said
But a cleaner solution is to use something like fos js routing which allows you to generate the routes from java script